# gammu receive sms message python fails

Tags: python, sms, sms-gateway, gammu

I have found a script on this website http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/run.html

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys

numparts = int(os.environ['DECODED_PARTS'])

# Are there any decoded parts?
if numparts == 0:
  print('No decoded parts!')
  sys.exit(1)

# Get all text parts
text = ''
for i in range(1, numparts + 1):
  varname = 'DECODED_%d_TEXT' % i
  if varname in os.environ:
    text = text + os.environ[varname]

# Do something with the text
f = open('/home/pi/output.txt','w')
f.write('Number %s have sent text: %s' % (os.environ['SMS_1_NUMBER'], text))
```

And i know that my gammu-smsd is working fine, because i can turn of my ledlamp on raspberry by sending sms to the raspberry, but my question is why is this script failing? nonthing is happening. and when I try to run the script by it self it also fails.

What I would like to do is just receive the sms and then read the content and save the content and phonenumber which sent the sms to a file.

I hope you understand my issue. 
Thank you in advance, all the best.

Answer (score 0):

In the gammu-smsd config file, you can use the file backend which does this for you automatically.

See this example from the gammu documentation
http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/config.html#files-service

```
[smsd]
Service = files
PIN = 1234
LogFile = syslog
InboxPath = /var/spool/sms/inbox/
OutboPpath = /var/spool/sms/outbox/
SentSMSPath = /var/spool/sms/sent/
ErrorSMSPath = /var/spool/sms/error/
```

Also see options for the file backend to tailor to your needs.
http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/config.html#files-backend-options

Hope this helps :)